# No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/trader"

Tags: php, pecl, trading

I am not sure if pecl.php.net is down or something but does this package still exist? Or was it discontinued?
I am running the following commands:

```
sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
sudo pecl install trader
```

And i am getting the following output:

```
Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
Channel "pecl.php.net" is not responding over http://, failed with 
message: Connection to `pecl.php.net:80' failed: Connection timed out
Trying channel "pecl.php.net" over https:// instead
Channel "pecl.php.net" is up to date

No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/trader"
install failed
```